# window.alert message is not showing Sqlite row data

Tags: javascript, android, sqlite, cordova

I'm developing an android app by `Cordova`. I'm reading values from a Sqlite table and showing into a table using `Javascript`.

```
function queryDB(tx) {

        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}

function querySuccess(tx, results) {

          var tblText='<table id="t01"><tr><th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> </tr>';
          var len = results.rows.length;
          for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
              tblText +='<tr onclick="alert('+results.rows.item(i).data+')"><td>' + results.rows.item(i).id +'</td><td>'+ results.rows.item(i).data+'</td></tr>';
              }
          tblText +="</table>";
          document.getElementById("tblDiv").innerHTML =tblText;
}
..
<body>
    ..
    <div id="tblDiv"></div>
    ..
</body>
..
```

'results.rows.item(i).data' shows the data when I use it in '' tag. But `alert` dialog never pops up by this part:

```
<tr onclick="alert('+results.rows.item(i).data+')"><td>'
```

I know that `onClick` shows `i` if I do it like this

```
<tr onclick="alert('+ i +')"><td>'
```

But I can't figure out why it doesn't show `results.rows.item(i).data` or `results.rows.item(i).data.toString()`

Any ideas?

Comment: you can't get like that(results.rows.item(i).data `outside querySuccess function`) assign some variable or assign to some fields get that values.

Comment: You need to use `JSON.stringify()` function. e.g `JSON.stringify(results.rows.item(i).data)` to get the value.

Comment: @frank Should I use it like this > `'<tr onclick="alert('+JSON.stringify(results.rows.item(i).data)+')"><td>'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok! I found my solution. After looking deep into my code I realized that with this piece of code:

```
tblText +='<tr onclick="alert('+results.rows.item(i).data+');"><td>'
```

The `alert` function would look like somethin like this:

```
alert(rowdata); //Assume rowdata is a string from my database
```

So obviously `Javascript` would look `rowdata` as a variable which will be `undefined` or `null`. So I changed the code to this:

```
tblText +='<tr onclick="alert("'+results.rows.item(i).data+'");"><td>'
```

So that the `alert` function would look like this:

```
alert("rowdata");
```

And now it works like a charm!